# php - json_encode quote encapsulate keys

Tags: php, json

For some reason json_encode is not encapsulating the keys for valid json?

```
$json = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++){   
    $datum = $result[$i];
    $mid = $datum->mid;
    $desc = $datum->description;
    $score = $datum->score;

    $json[$i] = array("desc"=>$desc,"score"=>$score);
}
 $json = json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
 echo $json;
```

This outputs as

```
[
{
desc: "audio receiver",
score: 0.81596649
},
{
desc: "gadget",
score: 0.69863933
} 
]
```

But `desc` and `score` should be `"desc"` and `"score"` for proper jsonlint

Comment: a typo in `for($i=0;$imid;` or is it intentional?

Comment: that was due to the `<` sign not being replaced with `&#60;`

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT option?

Comment: try `$json = json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );`

Comment: nope and nope - originally i didn't have the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT but when the json keys were not being properly quoted added them...